# Surface Tension on Micro and Nano Scales

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, surface-tension, non-newtonian-fluids

Dragonflies have holes scattered across the veins of their wings that are hypothesized to allow air to pass through but keep blood in. These holes are typically on the order of a few nanometers. The vein is several orders of magnitude larger.

Consider a simplified model where a single vein is a straight pipe with a pressure gradient and a few small holes are poked on one side along the length.

My question is whether the surface tension across these very small holes is a limiting factor on the pressure gradient across the pipe? Or does the small size of the hole not contribute at all?

I am also assuming for the moment the blood is Newtonian, but I recognize that may be a poor assumption.

**Addition**
For the sake of comparison, jumping spiders hemolymph is shear-thinning.

See Figure 8 from [Zhao, H., Yin, Y., & Zhong, Z. (2013). Arnold circulation and multi-optimal dynamic controlling mechanisms in dragonfly wings. Acta Mechanica Solida Sinica, 26(3), 237-244.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0894916613600221?via%3Dihub)
[image: Fig8]

Comment: interesting problem; is your schematic something like Figs. 1,2 in this paper (10.1007/s00707-013-1037-5)?

Comment: also, are you referring to the surface tension at the blood-air interface? because, from your description, i can visualize only a single fluid (i.e. blood) being transported in the pipe. and holes are present between veins, not inside a vein

Comment: Please provide a link, otherwise, I have no idea what you're referring to. That is the only possible fluid-fluid interface in the problem.

Comment: I am referring to the link in my first comment - Figs. 1,2 in this paper (10.1007/s00707-013-1037-5)

Comment: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00707-013-1037-5

Comment: As I mentioned, the veins have holes open to the air so the insect can breathe. There is a blood-air interface. https://doi.org/10.1016/S0894-9166(13)60022-1 Fig. 8.

Comment: ok. to see if the surface tension has any influence at such small scales, you can compute the elasto-capillary number = \gamma/E L. Here, \gamma is the surface tension at blood-air interface, E = stiffness of the vein and L = characteristic length scale - L could be taken as the radius of the small hole. if EC is quite small (< 0.01 or so), the elasto-capillary effects caused by surface tension on the deformation of vein/pressure changes in the vein are very small. in your case, I would expect the elasto-capillary to be huge because the radius of the hole is O(nm).

Comment: for eg. in this study (https://doi.org/10.1080/00218464.2011.575332), the authors noticed a sudden peak in the pressure at very small radii of the hole/bubble. this was due to elasto-capillary effects.

Comment: What does EC mean? You said E = stiffness, but never said what C was.

Comment: The paper you cited is for elastomers, the material is very different from a non-Newtonian fluid such as hemolymph.

Comment: there was a typo in my comment - replace EC with elasto-capillary number.  One thing I forgot to ask: does the air penetrate through the holes inside the vein (or pipe) and mix with the blood?

Comment: the paper I cited demonstrates the change in the pressure due to the surface-tension at the elastomer-bubble (air) interface. it was meant as an example. in your case, you are accounting for the surface tension at the blood-air interface, where both the blood and air are in simultaneous contact with a portion of the vein. the underlying physical principle in your case and the paper is the same.

Comment: Yes, of course, it does, otherwise, it's not functioning to help the insects breathe.